# "I like your shoes". Is this sentence ambiguous when it is said to someone working in a shoe company?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, sentence-meaning, idiomatic-language, idioms-in-context

When you are in a shopping center and are inside a shop and start talking the woman who always help you and say to this person:

**"I like your shoes."**

I think the **"the liking"** here can be ambiguous:

1- I might be talking about the shoes that she is wearing.

2- I might be talking about the shoes made by her company ( for example I mean they are always good on me, or they fit me well, or I like the style etc.)

Is that right? Or does it always refer to the shoes the person is wearing, so I should say something like **"I like the shoes made by your company."** in order to specifically refer to the shoes that are sold in that shop.

Comment: This would be the same in whatever your language is and is not really about English.

Comment: Is the shoe-shop worker the same sex as the customer?

Comment: Yes, it's ambiguous, but the meaning should be clear from the context - are you looking at the shoes she is wearing, or telling her why you often come to the shop where she works?

Comment: @KateBunting Yes, but it is not attributable to English. That would be true in just about any language.

Comment: Personally, I would find it a little odd if a customer in the shoe shop where I work said 'I like your shoes', because we would be surrounded by shoes, and I might expect a native speaker to say something like 'I like the/those shoes you're wearing' exactly because of that.

Comment: I suppose in some languages this might be marked by a T-V distinction, so "I like thy shoes" (singular) could refer to the singular person's shoes, but "I like your shoes" (plural) would relate to the companiy's shoes.  But it's a bit of a stretch.

Comment: To be clear, if the customer said 'I like your shoes' I might wonder if they were trying to pick me up.

Comment: It would often been heard as a witty *double entendre*.  Both meanings are present, understood, and playfully (flirtatiously?) presented.  In this case the *liking* is intended to be ambiguous.